# Should I use a plastic vapor barrier on foundation walls?

Tags: vapor-barrier

I’m renovating my partially-below-grade guest room, and I currently have it stripped down to the cinder blocks. The only other part I’ve left in place are the vertical 1/2” plywood strips that are attached to the cinder blocks every 16” with concrete screws.

My original plan was to do this layering:
Cinder block > 1/2” plywood strips > 6 mil plastic > 1” polyiso > 2x4 > drywall

I’m going to be putting that together, but I’m double guessing myself on whether to use the plastic sheet as a vapor barrier. I have no idea whether there is any vapor barrier on the outside of the cinder block, but I doubt it.

I’m in East Tennessee, where our winters are coldish and our summers are moderate.

Comment: primary heating climate have vapor barrier on the warm side...   between insulation and drywall.  do you air condition this space?

Answer (score 2):

The effect you are concerned about is called "interstitial condensation", in your case, the condensation that occurs within wall cavities.

Your vapour barrier must be installed so that the dew point falls within the xps: the temperature at the VB must be high enough so that no condensation forms at the VB. This is why in heating climates it is placed on the inside side of the wall.

To place a VB against the cinder blocks or a concrete wall, especially below grade, is best accomplished by using XPS foam boards (the pink or blue styrofoam). If this is below grade, usually 1in thick suffices to keep the temperature high enough on the inside side of the XPS, and low enough on the outside side of the XPS to prevent condensation.

[image]

Once you choose for XPS, do not apply another VB (6mil plastic sheet) on the inside side of the wall. The insulation in between must breathe to stay dry, and inwards is then the only option.

Image: https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/article/the-flash-and-batt-method

Comment: Great reply!! That’s fantastic. One wall is above grade, so that’s the wall I’m using polyiso on. The other wall is below grade on a slope from 5’ to 0” so I got XPS for that wall. I’ll scrap my plastic sheeting plans entirely.

Comment: @SMCutter that's good news. Remember to upvote the answers you like.